# ifstream is failing to open my file

Tags: c++, file, ifstream

I am creating a program that uses information from a simple text file. However, it keeps getting caught by my .fail() function every time. The file is just called Test.txt, and is located in the same folder as my .exe file for the program. I'm not sure why it keeps hitting the .fail()

Here is the code for my ifstream creation, opening the file, and my .fail() loop.

```
ifstream input;
    input.open(fileNameIn.c_str());
    if(input.fail()){

        cout << "File named " << fileNameIn << " did not open successfully."     << endl;

    }
```

Comment: As far as I can tell? I get no errors on it if thats what you mean

Comment: Have you tried printing out `fileNameIn.c_str()` to check it is what you think it is?

Comment: When the fail statement is output is the file name correct (without any extra whitespace)?

Comment: @Kvothe No not yet. I'll give it a shot

Comment: You could also try (for debugging purposes) hard coding the file name when opening the `ifstream`.

Comment: @Kvothe The filename prints out correctly

Comment: Print out your working directory, too. And try it with an absolute path.

Comment: @Historiun How about hard-coding the name into the `open` call instead of using `fileNameIn`?  This way, we know exactly what we're trying to open instead of the name hiding behind a string variable.

Comment: I thought I didnt need an absolute path. The txt file is in the same directory as the .txt file

Comment: what happens if you call `bad()` instead of `fail()`? (to identify whether the bad or fail bit is set)

Comment: @PaulMcKenzie it cant be hardcoded. The file name will come from user input

Comment: For testing it can be to help identify your problem.

Comment: @Historiun `it cant be hardcoded. `  I'm asking you to hardcode the name to ensure that it actually can be opened.  That is what any programmer would do instead of playing guessing games.  Maybe the filename string has invisible control characters in it -- who knows...

Comment: Normal debugging technique is to hard code something that is known to rule out a piece of code as being at fault.

Comment: Nearly every time this question comes up it's because the working directory of your program isn't where you think it is.

Comment: @user657267 And almost all of the other times, the `filename` variable does not contain the string the poster is claiming.

Comment: Ok. I printed out the fileNameIn as I have it written. It outputs the correct file name. I also hardcoded the file name and ran it. Still gave me the failed to open error

Comment: Try `ifstream input ("Test.txt");` instead of `input.open(fileNameIn.c_str());` and then try `if(!input.is_open())` instead of `if(input.fail())`.

Comment: @Historiun First, printing the name doesn't rule out the possibility of control characters in the string name.  To test for control characters, you have to inspect the string (use the "memory" window to view the character sequence) to make sure that the string is free of non-printable character.  Second, since you hardcoded the name, this means that the file is probably not in the directory you expected it to be in.

Comment: I've double and triple checked. The test file is in the same directory as the .exe file. Isn't that where it needs to be if I'm not using the path?

Comment: If this is windows make sure you didn't do something silly like check the box that says 'hide extensions for known file types' in explorer and make it so your files name is really 'Test.txt.txt' vs 'Test.txt' like you expect

Comment: @Historiun open a command prompt and do a `dir` if you haven't done so already.  `kmcnamee` brings up a good point...

Comment: I made sure that that wasn't the issue. But i think I did figure it out. I did have it in the wrong directory. Thank you everyone

Answer (score -1):

Try `input.open(strSourceFile.c_str(), std::ifstream::in);` and see if that helps.

This is the pattern I use for reading files using c++

```
//
// FileAccessor is just my wrapper around ifstream
// inside the constuctor: 
//    ifstream.open(strSourceFile.c_str(),std::ifstream::in); is called
//
FileAccessor fileAccessor(textFile);

while(fileAccessor.good()) {
    fileAccessor.getline(lineOfText);
    ...
    if(fileAccessor.eof()) break;
}
```

Per `http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/ios/ios/good/`
`bool good() const;`

`Check whether state of stream is good`
`Returns true if none of the stream's error state flags (eofbit, failbit and badbit) is set.`

You could have a flag set in the loop to see if it even ever entered the loop, if not, then inspect the error bit flags.

Comment: `ifstream` will **always** add `in` to the list of flags passed to the filebuf constructor.